# How to convert Backbone fetched object to proper Handlebars JSON Object?

Tags: json, backbone.js, handlebars.js

Currently I have an issue with getting back a proper JSON object I'm fetching with Backbone fetch() and putting it into a Handlebars template.

See below my code, I have made a ugly workaround for now to test my Backend API
When converting to JSON with *.toJSON(), it just adds an extra object in-between and I don't need this extra object

```
Object [0]
--> books
----> Object [0]
------> Array of book
--------> book
--------> cities
```

JSON

```
{
"books": [
    {
        "book": 00001,
        "cities": [
            "TEST"
        ]
    },
    {
        "book": 00002,
        "cities": [
            "TEST"
        ]
    },
    {
        "book": 00003,
        "cities": [
            "TEST"
        ]
    }
],
"more": true
}
```

JavaScript

```
    var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({

    default: {
        book: 0,
        cities: ["TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3"]
    },

    url: function () {
        return ".list.json";
    }

});

var Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Book,
    url: ".list.json"
});

var BooksView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){

        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.collection = new Books();
        this.collection.fetch();
        this.source = $('.e-books-template').html();

        // Use an extern template
        this.template = Handlebars.compile(this.source);

        var self = this;
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function () {
                self.render();
            },

            error: function () {
                console.log("ERROR IN BooksView");
            }
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        var collect = JSON.stringify(this.collection);
        collect = collect.slice(1, -1);
        var html = this.template($.parseJSON(collect));
        this.$el.html(html);
    }
});


var booksView = new BooksView({ });

$(document).ready(function(){
    booksView.$el = $('.e-books-content');
});
```

Comment: Are you looking for http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON ?

Comment: That is what I tried but this doesn't work the way I would want as it add the extra object inbetween

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A Backbone collection expects an array of models but your JSON provides an object with the array under a `books` key. [Parse the server response](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) to format the data :

   ```
   var Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({
       model: Book,
       url: ".list.json",
       parse: function(data) {
           return data.books;
       }
   });
   ```
2. Pass your data to your template via http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON ,

   ```
   // directly as an array in your template
   var html = this.template(this.collection.toJSON());

   // under a books key
   var html = this.template({
       books: this.collection.toJSON()
   });
   ```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/8jdb13jg/

Comment: I tried this but when I add the parse I get an error in the logs "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,", I checked the official documentation for this and it should be correct, however this doesn't work.

Comment: A typo somewhere? Here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/8jdb13jg/ that emulates your setup.

Comment: I thought that too it but adding the "parse" is giving this error. I even just copy/pasted, still the same error.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I had a comma in my HTML, instead of a dot :-(